# use v2ray proxy settings in cmd for python command

Tags: python, cmd, proxy, v2ray

I have a django project and I should run it like this
`python manage.py runserver`
in process of running the program it needs to connect to an IP which is blocked in my location and I want to use my v2ray config to access that IP but v2rayN app doesn't affect cmd

I found this solution to set proxy for git
`git config --global http.proxy http://proxyUsername:proxyPassword@proxy.server.com:port`
can I use it on python as well? and I don't know what should I fill **proxyUserName**, **ProxyPassword**, **proxy.server.com** and **port**. I only have my vmess connection code can you help me extract these information from my vmess code?

Comment: Your v2rayN will start a proxy locally which may be http://localhost:10809, which can be found in v2rayN. Then set the environment variables HTTP_PROXY and HTTPS_PROXT to this address.

Answer (score 3):

run v2rayN as administrator, then a toggle button will appear, labeled "Enable Tun". I think that will solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

In the "v2ray UI" click on "Copy HTTP proxy Shell Export Line"

The MacOS export is something like this:

```
export http_proxy=http://127.0.0.1:1087;export https_proxy=http://127.0.0.1:1087;export ALL_PROXY=socks5://127.0.0.1:1080
```

Run this line in the terminal(command line)
Then run your commands