How to use v2rayN in windows wsl2 Ubuntu
I have v2rayN app in windows, when I set it on global it will not change my IP in terminals  and I want to use it in wsl2 Ubuntu for my projects.
I tried to use it by connecting the port in ubuntu by
export http_proxy="socks5://127.0.0.1:10808"
export https_proxy="socks5://127.0.0.1:10808"

but I got Failed to connect to 127.0.0.1 port 10808 after 0 ms: Connection refused.
how can I do that?


⭐️ If the above-mentioned solution is applied, it will require v2rayN to open LAN connection, and changes in Windows IPv4 Address may lead to proxy failure. Here is my effective solution:

WSL Proxy Configuration 2024 New Solution (using v2rayN as an example) - Simple and Effective
Introduction
In the China region, using curl/wget raw.github... or git commands in WSL2 often fails due to slow internet connectivity. Therefore, network configuration is necessary while setting up the environment. However, WSL2, implemented via a virtual machine, does not share internet with Windows like WSL1, making it difficult to use the host machine’s network proxy.
Common online tutorials include adjusting the DNS server address or using a LAN to implement the proxy, such as:

WSL2配置V2ray等http代理服务器
WSL2内使用Windows的v2ray代理
WSL 2 网络配置
WSL2 中访问宿主机 Windows 的代理
...

However, these solutions are challenging to implement, and slight mishaps (like incorrect Windows Firewall settings) can cause all efforts to fail. Moreover, with recent updates in WSL, setting proxy environment variables might result in the message: WSL: A localhost proxy configuration was detected but not mirrored into WSL. WSL in NAT mode does not support localhost proxies. Thus, proxy settings fail. WSL: localhost configuration detected but not mirrored to WSL. NAT mode WSL does not support localhost.#10753
I proposes a new solution for configuring network-related proxy in WSL using network mirroring, greatly simplifying the cumbersome setup process, and provides an example configuration of v2rayN without the need to modify DNS, disable firewall settings, or enable LAN sharing, making it a safe operation.
System Requirements

Windows 11 23H2
WSL 2.2.4.0
Ubuntu 22.04

Configuration Process
WSL Installation
Windows Subsystem for Linux (WSL) Installation Steps
After installation, run WSL to test if it starts normally. Note that the version installed from the Microsoft Store is Ubuntu 22.04!
Configuration

Mirrored Mode Networking Explanation

On computers running Windows 11 22H2 or higher, you can set networkingMode=mirrored in the .wslconfig file under [wsl2] to enable Mirrored Mode Networking. This feature changes WSL to a new network architecture which aims to “mirror” Windows network interfaces into Linux, adding new network functionalities and enhancing compatibility.


Create a .wslconfig file under C:\Users\your_user_name\, with content:
[experimental]
autoMemoryReclaim=gradual  
networkingMode=mirrored
dnsTunneling=true
firewall=true
autoProxy=false

networkingMode=mirrored to enable mirrored mode. autoProxy=false to disable auto proxy and prevent v2rayN from switching proxy modes (like clear <-> set system proxy) which prompts WSL to restart with An Http proxy change has been detected on the host...
Restart WSL from Command Prompt:
for bash
Re-enter WSL, edit vim ~/.bashrc, and add:
# proxy setting
alias proxy='
    export HTTPS_PROXY="http://127.0.0.1:10809";
    export HTTP_PROXY="http://127.0.0.1:10809";
    export ALL_PROXY="socks5://127.0.0.1:10808";
    git config --global http.proxy "socks5://127.0.0.1:10808";
    git config --global https.proxy "socks5://127.0.0.1:10808";
'
alias noproxy='
    unset HTTPS_PROXY;
    unset HTTP_PROXY;
    unset ALL_PROXY;
    git config --global --unset  http.proxy;
    git config --global --unset  https.proxy;
'

If you do not want to set a git proxy, simply remove the git-related parts. Port numbers can be obtained from v2rayN (software interface at the lower-left corner):
v2rayN interface pic
To activate the settings, run source ~/.bashrc.
Before starting the proxy each time, type proxy. To stop using it, type noproxy.
for zsh
If using zsh, perform similar operations, edit vim ~./zshrc and add:
# proxy setting
proxy () {
  export HTTPS_PROXY="http://127.0.0.1:10809";
  export HTTP_PROXY="http://127.0.0.1:10809";
  export ALL_PROXY="socks5://127.0.0.1:10808";
  git config --global http.proxy "socks5://127.0.0.1:10808";
  git config --global https.proxy "socks5://127.0.0.1:10808";
  echo "Proxy on"
}
noproxy () {
  unset HTTPS_PROXY;
  unset HTTP_PROXY;
  unset ALL_PROXY;
  git config --global --unset  http.proxy;
  git config --global --unset  https.proxy;
  echo "HTTP Proxy off"
}

Testing
wget www.google.com



in v2ray -> Setting -> OptionSetting -> Socks port should be 10808 and Allow connection from LAN should be enable

In your WSL2 Ubuntu terminal, you can set the proxy environment variables like this:
export http_proxy="socks5://YOUR_WINDOWS_IP:10808"
export https_proxy="socks5://YOUR_WINDOWS_IP:10808"

Replace YOUR_WINDOWS_IP with the actual IP address of your Windows host. You can find this IP address by running ipconfig in the Windows Command Prompt or PowerShell. then search for IPv4 Address .

The question is not on-topic for Stack Overflow as defined in the [help]. Please don't answer such questions; instead, you should flag them for attention and they will be closed or migrated appropriately.

what is the on-topic of stack overflow? I'm a programmer and I couldn't use Arbitrum testnet just because of my nationality and there is similar questions in here but not for WSL like https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76278689/use-v2ray-proxy-settings-in-cmd-for-python-command

The question is about using this program, not about programming.  Stack Overflow is for questions about writing programs, not about using or configuring programs written by others.  Yes, there may be other off-topic questions that need removing - don't encourage people to add to them!

I see. for this kind of filtering that we have just v2ray and nekoray protocols works. the apps are different but configs are similar. for example in nekobox port is 2080. if you have problem with v2rayN client I can change it to v2ray and nekoray that covers all clients.
